# While keyboard visible white flash is showing in Jetpack Compose(Android)

Tags: android, user-interface, keyboard, android-jetpack-compose, user-experience

While the keyboard is activating I am updating the bottom padding using the following code

```
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(android.R.id.content)) { view, insets ->
                val bottom = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom
                view.updatePadding(bottom = bottom)
                insets
            }
```

but when I open the keyboard white color flashes before opening the keyboard.

when the background color is white the flash is not visible but if I use any other color the white flash comes while the keyboard is visible.

if I remove this code, the content is overlapped with the keyboard when the keyboard is active and the scroll is not working.